# Multiple errors after upgrading to 4.7.21 and Joomla 3.7.3

Tags: joomla, 4.7

E.g. here: https://www.evergreenmtb.org/support-us/donate

All those files (listed in Chrome's Console w/ errors) do exist, permissions are 644... what am I missing? This started after upgrading to 4.7.21 and Joomla 3.7.3.

Any pointers greatly appreciated : )

Comment: $civicrm_root variable should not have path with symlinks in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by [civicrm.root] using
https://www.mydomain.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/

while it should be using
http://www.example.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/

The $civicrm_root variable is correct in both civicrm.settings.php files so I'm really confused why CiviCRM cannot pull the civicrm.root variable correctly.

Comment: Hi MtnPavlas, great that you were about to fix it, Can you please log this in to JIRA as there was work on the civicrm.root stuff in 4.7.21

Comment: Jira issue created here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20843